# How to have Vue dynamic button disabled based on checkbox from list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created a Todo app while learning Vue, so far so good. I have on issue where initially I set the tasks delete button to disabled and want to have it be enabled only if the checkbox related is checked. As of now when I click any task checkbox ALL the buttons are affected. Not sure how you would create a relation to the 2 elements.

```
 <template>
        <div class="mt-5 todos-list">
          <div
            v-for="todo in todos"
            :key="todo.id"
            class="flex justify-between pb-4 todos-item"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center mr-10 todos-item__checkbox">
              <input
                v-model="checkboxes"
                :value="todo.task.title"
                type="checkbox"
                class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 border-2 border-red-500 appearance-none checked:bg-red-600 checked:border-transparent"
                @change="checkBoxChecked($event)"
              />
              <label for="todo" class="text-lg font-medium todos-checkbox ">{{
                todo.task.title
              }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="todos-item__button">
              <button
                class="rounded-lg btn btn-delete"
                :class="{ disabled: btnDisabled[index] }"
                type="button"
                :disabled="btnDisabled[index]"
                @click="deleteTask(todo.task.id)"
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
        <AddTodo @addTodo="addTask" />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          checkboxes: [],
          btnDisabled: [],
          todos: [
            {
              task: {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Go to store',
                isComplete: false
              }
            },
            {
              task: {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Go for walk',
                isComplete: false
              }
            },
            {
              task: {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Take dog out',
                isComplete: false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
  mounted() {
    const disableArr = this.todos.map((el) => true)
    this.btnDisabled.push(...disableArr)
  },
      methods: {
        addTask(title) {
          this.todos.push({
            task: {
              id: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000),
              title,
              isComplete: false
            }
          })
        },
        deleteTask(id) {
          const index = this.todos.findIndex((item) => item.id === id)
          this.todos.splice(index, 1)
        },
         checkBoxChecked(event, index) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.btnDisabled = this.btnDisabled.map((el, i) => index !== i)
  } else {
    this.btnDisabled = this.btnDisabled.map((el, i) => index === i)
  }
}
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you only just have one boolean state for all of your todos. Maybe it will work if you change `btnDisabled` data into array, so each todo will have their own disabled or not disabled state on their own.

Here are one way of what I'm trying to point out

**Change btnDisabled into array**

```
btnDisabled = this.todos.map(el => true)
```

**Add index to v-for**

```
v-for="(todo,index) in todos"
```

**Pass index to @change**

```
@change="checkBoxChecked($event,index)"
```

**Modify checkBoxChecked Method**

```
checkBoxChecked(event, index) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.btnDisabled = this.btnDisabled.map((el,i) => index === i ? false : true)
  } else {
    this.btnDisabled = this.btnDisabled.map((el,i) => index === i ? true : false)
  }
}
```

**bind disabled to specific index of btnDisabled**

```
:disabled="btnDisabled[index]"
```

Hope this solve your issue

Comment: Hi @Qoyyima Fias Salam! thanks for the input! clearing things up for me. The only issue I am seeing now is the checkBoxChecked method is returning this error:

Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression

Comment: Hi @MonTOne , happy to help! maybe you can change 'index === i ? false : true' to become 'index !== i' , and 'index === i ? true : false' into 'index === i' , and see if the error still shows. And if the answer really answer your question, please set the answer as accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: Yes I actually changed that before which removed error but still not functioning correctly. On initial page load only the FIRST instance of the button is disabled. I tried creating array map on the mounted lifecycle which solved that issue. What happens now is when I click on one checkbox it removes the correct disabled state but then the other items also remove the disabld state.

Comment: updated original post with NEW changes